Gauge Fixing Rigorously
The question is pretty simple:
Is it always possible to do gauge fixing?
Suppose we have a $(D+1)$ dimensional base manifold and we have $G$ as the gauge group.
A gauge theory is defined as a $G$-principal bundle over the base manifold.
To do a gauge fixing then usually means to choose, in each gauge orbit in each fiber, a given reference point and this is achieved by imposing a condition on the connection, like $f(\omega)=0$.
Is this always possible or there are cases when some obstructions to the procedure prevents gauge fixing, maybe related to the relation (bad wording, sorry) between the dimension of the base manifold and the gauge group?

No, there are Gribov ambiguities.

If you could write a little resume about this it will be a very nice answer
